# How to display a web page in a frame from a jsoup document in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jsoup

I have to make a Web Browser, displaying the web pages from a DOM tree. I have the DOM tree done using jsoup library, but I don't know how to display the web page on a JEditorPane.

I have this:

```
Document domTree = BackEnd.getInstance().getDOM(linkBar.getText(), "GET", null);
```

which makes a Document (domTree), as a HTML document, that has the DOM tree of the web site entered in the link bar. 
How can I use this document to display the web page on that JEditorPane? Or do I have to use a different thing than JEditorPane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually JEditorPane is used to render HTML in Java swing. You just need to set the content type. Since you have the document object ready try

```
editor.setContentType( "text/html" );    
editor.setText( domTree.html() );
```

Comment: Yes, that does it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have another question. JEditorPane can display only http pages or can display https too?

Comment: Yes. It can display https as well.

Comment: If I display the web page with setText(), it displays the images as well? I ask this because in this moment it doesn't display any images, only text.

Comment: No. It wont. JEditorPane has limited html and css support. It does'nt support javascript or applets. It was not intended to be used as a web browser. If you want a browser try Lobo-Browser(http://lobobrowser.org/java-browser.jsp) or other opensource ones.